# List of all arrays not contained in other lists of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of two dimensional points, represented as two element long lists/arrays. E.g.:

```
points = 
      [[ 10.       ,  10.       ],
       [ 11.       ,  10.       ],
       [ 10.5      ,   9.1339746],
       [ 10.5      ,  10.       ],
       [ 10.75     ,   9.5669873],
       [ 10.25     ,   9.5669873],
       [  2.       ,   2.       ],
       [  3.       ,   2.       ],
       [  2.5      ,   1.1339746],
       [  2.5      ,   2.       ],
       [  2.75     ,   1.5669873],
       [  2.25     ,   1.5669873]]
```

I now want to have a list which does not contain certain elements of this first list.

```
exclude = [[2., 2.], [3., 2.], [2.5, 2.]]
```

Unfortunately

```
new_list = [p for p in points if p not in exclude]
```

will produce

```
[[ 10.       ,  10.       ],
 [ 11.       ,  10.       ],
 [ 10.5      ,   9.1339746],
 [ 10.5      ,  10.       ],
 [ 10.75     ,   9.5669873],
 [ 10.25     ,   9.5669873],
 [  2.75     ,   1.5669873],
 [  2.25     ,   1.5669873]]
```

instead of

```
[[ 10.       ,  10.       ],
 [ 11.       ,  10.       ],
 [ 10.5      ,   9.1339746],
 [ 10.5      ,  10.       ],
 [ 10.75     ,   9.5669873],
 [ 10.25     ,   9.5669873],
 [  2.5      ,   1.1339746],
 [  2.75     ,   1.5669873],
 [  2.25     ,   1.5669873]]
```

It seems Python removes all elements here that have at least one element in common (and not all in common :/ ).

Is there any nice/short/elegant way to exclude elements if they are not completely contained in the first list?

Comment: Are these lists or arrays? `in` for arrays doesn't quite work like you'd expect.

Comment: it works for lists without any problem. Is it numpy arrays or lists?

Comment: It works just fine: http://ideone.com/JtRnc5

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non-existent problem with working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Since this question has been tagged `numpy`, I'm assuming `points` is a NumPy array. If that's true, you could generate a boolean mask (array) using `np.logical_and` and `np.logical_or`:

```
import numpy as np

points = np.array(
      [[ 10.       ,  10.       ],
       [ 11.       ,  10.       ],
       [ 10.5      ,   9.1339746],
       [ 10.5      ,  10.       ],
       [ 10.75     ,   9.5669873],
       [ 10.25     ,   9.5669873],
       [  2.       ,   2.       ],
       [  3.       ,   2.       ],
       [  2.5      ,   1.1339746],
       [  2.5      ,   2.       ],
       [  2.75     ,   1.5669873],
       [  2.25     ,   1.5669873]])

exclude = [[2., 2.], [3., 2.], [2.5, 2.]]

mask = np.logical_or.reduce(
    [np.logical_and.reduce(
        [points[:,idx] == ex[idx] for idx in range(len(ex))]) for ex in exclude])

new_points = points[~mask]
print(new_points)
```

prints

```
[[ 10.         10.       ]
 [ 11.         10.       ]
 [ 10.5         9.1339746]
 [ 10.5        10.       ]
 [ 10.75        9.5669873]
 [ 10.25        9.5669873]
 [  2.5         1.1339746]
 [  2.75        1.5669873]
 [  2.25        1.5669873]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also view the 2D array as a 1D array and then use `np.in1d`.

```
#Using @unutbu array's.

def view_1d(arr):
    return arr.view(np.dtype((np.void,arr.dtype.itemsize * arr.shape[1])))

points_1d=view_1d(points)
exclude_1d=view_1d(exclude)

print points[~np.in1d(points_1d,exclude_1d)]

[[ 10.         10.       ]
 [ 11.         10.       ]
 [ 10.5         9.1339746]
 [ 10.5        10.       ]
 [ 10.75        9.5669873]
 [ 10.25        9.5669873]
 [  2.5         1.1339746]
 [  2.75        1.5669873]
 [  2.25        1.5669873]]
```

Just to double check the trickery is working and some ballpark timings:

```
points=np.random.rand(1E6,2)
points=np.around(points,1)

exclude=np.random.rand(1E2,2)
exclude=np.around(exclude,1)


t = time.time()
mask1 = ~(np.in1d(view_1d(points),view_1d(exclude)))

print time.time()-t
#0.469238996506

t = time.time()
mask2 = ~np.logical_or.reduce(
    [np.logical_and.reduce(
        [points[:,idx] == ex[idx] for idx in range(len(ex))]) for ex in exclude])

print time.time()-t
#7.13628792763

#Just to check this is doing what I think its doing.
print np.all(mask1==mask2)
True
```

Timings are just for generating the mask. Both methods appear to scale similarly, I just showed large arrays to (hopefully) compensate for not using `timeit`.

Answer (score -1):

1. Your code as posted is not syntactically valid.
2. It produces (once corrected) your desired result:

--

```
[[10.0, 10.0],
 [11.0, 10.0],
 [10.5, 9.1339746],
 [10.5, 10.0],
 [10.75, 9.5669873],
 [10.25, 9.5669873],
 [2.5, 1.1339746],
 [2.75, 1.5669873],
 [2.25, 1.5669873]]
```

See: http://ideone.com/7LOpa6

```
points =  [[ 10.       ,  10.       ],
       [ 11.       ,  10.       ],
       [ 10.5      ,   9.1339746],
       [ 10.5      ,  10.       ],
       [ 10.75     ,   9.5669873],
       [ 10.25     ,   9.5669873],
       [  2.       ,   2.       ],
       [  3.       ,   2.       ],
       [  2.5      ,   1.1339746],
       [  2.5      ,   2.       ],
       [  2.75     ,   1.5669873],
       [  2.25     ,   1.5669873]]
exclude = [[2., 2.], [3., 2.], [2.5, 2.]]

print [p for p in points if p not in exclude]
```

Comment: Your answer entirely misses the problem. At least one of the objects involved is a numpy array. `in` does bizarre things that actually do produce the OP's problem for arrays.

Comment: @user2357112 None of the objects involved in the question is a numpy array. You're complaining that I haven't formulated a different question, and answered that.

Comment: The demonstrated behavior matches numpy's bizarre array `__contains__` semantics, and the OP explicitly mentions arrays and used a numpy tag. Why would you assume there are no arrays involved?